# How to pass azure-pipelines.yml variables to ARM templates with AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I'm starting to work with Azure and tried these steps:

- I added a secret to an Azure Vault.
- I linked a service principal to my Azure DevOps pipelines.
- I created a variable group linked to my vault.
- I created a variable group with some variables.
- I created a azure-pipelines.yaml with a variables: group: group1 group: group2 part
- I have `- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` with a template with parameters. How do I satisfy the paramters from the variable groups?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have a try using **overrideParameters** parameter for the task to override your ARM template's parameters with the variables defined in your variable groups. Check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) for more parameters about this task.

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      inputs:
        azureResourceManagerConnection: <connection>

        overrideParameters: -storageAcctName azurerg -Username $(vmusername) -azureKeyVaultName $(fabrikamFibre)
```

For accessing AzureKeyVault, you can also use [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) to get your secrets in your build pipeline, or integrate KeyVault to your ARM template as @Daniel Mann pointed out. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault) for Microsoft official tutorial.

Comment: another (probably worse) way of doing this - you can use powershell to process those variables and call the template

Answer (score -4):

There are some limited scenarios where using variable groups in conjunction with YAML pipelines make sense, namely if you have a secret that *isn't* in keyvault that you need to store securely.

However, there are much better ways to manage this scenario. Remember, pipeline variables (including variable groups) should be for *pipeline* values, **not** application configuration. Tightly coupling your continuous delivery platform to your application's configuration just makes it harder to replicate your deployment process locally or migrate to a different continuous delivery provider in the future.

That said, here are a few recommended alternatives:

1. Add a `AzureKeyVault` step to your pipeline in order to retrieve secrets from the keyvault.
2. Link your ARM template directly to the keyvault; ARM templates have native support for keyvault parameters:

   "adminPassword": {
   "reference": {
   "keyVault": {
   "id": "/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/"
   },
   "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
   }
   }
3. Write your application to retrieve secrets directly from the keyvault at runtime.

Comment: why do you think so? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#variables

Comment: Do you have anything to support this? Variable groups are supported with YAML pipeline. Additionally they are leveraged to store deployment secrets that may not exist in a Key Vault. Additionally I have used ADO variable groups to populate Key Vault Secrets.

Comment: I wasn't saying you *can't*, I was saying you *generally shouldn't*. The scenario you outlined (a secret that isn't in keyvault) is valid, but also wasn't what the question was about. The rest of what I said 3 years ago, I stand by, downvotes or no.